# SQL Server connection using tedius and sequelize in NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server, express, sequelize.js

Getting below error when trying to connect SQL Server Local database in **NodeJs** **Sequelize**.

> name: 'SequelizeHostNotFoundError',
>       message: 'Failed to connect to abcdd\SQL2K12:1433 - getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND abcdd\SQL2K12',
>       code: 'ESOCKET

Below are my configuration settings and the credentials are correct

```
    "use_env_variable": false,
    "username": "username",
    "password": "password@123",
    "database": "db_test",
    "host": "abcdd\\SQL2K12",  //actual db hotsname is abcdd\SQL2K12
    "dialect": "mssql",
    "operatorsAliases": false,
    "dialectOptions": {
      "encrypt": true,
      "trustedConnection": true
    }
```

In SSMS its working fine. And is there issue with port number? As I am not using a port in SSMS.

Comment: On which port is SQL server running?

Comment: Also try to use connection string in the host.

Comment: I am using corporate server hosted database. Can you please provide full configuration settings? and How can I check port in SSMS?

Answer (score 1):

For me works adding `instanceName` instead of putting server: `'SERVER\SQLSERVER2K06'`,
just put `"SERVER"`.

```
var config = {
  server: 'SERVER',
  authentication: {
    type: 'default',
    options: {
      userName: 'user', 
      password: '*****' 
      }
  },
  options: {
      database: 'NAME',
      instanceName: 'SQLSERVER2K06' /*It Works! */
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for tedious: 
options.instanceName

The instance name to connect to. The SQL Server Browser service must be running on the database server, and UDP port 1434 on the database server must be reachable.
(no default)
Mutually exclusive with options.port.

check the comments: 
https://github.com/tediousjs/node-mssql/issues/130

var config = {
userName: 'test01',
password: 'test01',
server: 'localhost',
options: {
"database":"TestDB",
"instanceName": "SQL2012"
}
};

in your case 
var config = { server: 'abcdd', options: {"instanceName": "SQL2K12" } };

Also, make sure TCP enabled on your SQL Server: Sql Server Configuration Manager > SQL Server Network Configuration > Protocols for SQLSERVER > TCP/IP

Comment: I am trying to connect db using Sequalize not directly using tedious. Can you give example config for Sequelize

Comment: in the comments at github, for sequelize:

    "username": "username",
    "password": "password@123",
    "database": "db_test",
    "host": "abcdd",  //actual db hotsname is abcdd\SQL2K12
    "dialect": "mssql",
    "operatorsAliases": false,
    "dialectOptions": {
"instanceName": "SQL2K12"
    }